# I send information from the view for controller using html.beginform and it changes the whole view of the page - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, view

I want to send information to controller and I use html.beginform, but this function changes the whole view of page(cshtmlenter image description here).
I tried to change the place of the brackets, then it pass does not change the view but pass null.
I add to images of the view, what I am expect to get and what I get.
expect: https://ibb.co/1vyxRz9
https://ibb.co/gmx80z5
Thanks for the helpers.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmPayment", "Ticket", new
{
    Title = Model.tickets[0].MovieName,
    Price = Model.tickets[0].Price.ToString(),
}))
{

    <form class="credit-card" action="ConfirmPayment" method="post">

        <div class="form-header">

            <h4 class="title">Credit card detail</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="form-body" required>
            <!-- Card Number -->
            <input type="text" class="card-number" placeholder="Card Number">

            <!-- Date Field -->
            <div class="date-field" required>
                <div class="month">
                    <select name="Month">
                        <option name="Month" value="January">January</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="February">February</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="March">March</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="April">April</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="May">May</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="June">June</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="July">July</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="August">August</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="September">September</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="October">October</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="November">November</option>
                        <option name="Month" value="December">December</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="year">
                    <select name="Year">
                        <option name="Year" value="2020">2020</option>
                        <option name="Year" value="2021">2021</option>
                        <option name="Year" value="2022">2022</option>
                        <option name="Year" value="2023">2023</option>
                        <option name="Year" value="2024">2024</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Card Verification Field -->
            <div class="card-verification" required>
                <div class="cvv-input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="CVV">
                </div>
                <div class="cvv-details">
                    <p>3 or 4 digits usually found <br> on the signature strip</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Buttons -->
            <input class="btnProcced" value="Proceed" type="submit" />
            <input class="btnPaypal" value="Pay With Paypal" type="button" onclick="location.href='https://www.paypal.com/il/home?locale.x=he_IL'" />
        </div>


        

    </form>
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the image of what you are getting. as I can see, you have only added url of what is expected.. Are you getting any console error as well?

Comment: I added what iam getting too.
https://ibb.co/gmx80z5

Comment: @KushalSeth, I added image in my comment